# AWS EC2 instance not able to execute user data script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to get the aws user data to download a powershell script from S3 bucket and then run it on the EC2 instance after the instance has already been built.

I put following into the user data of the EC2 instance but even the "C:\Temp" folder is not getting created, and of course the script doesn't get downloaded or run:-

```
<powershell>
New-Item -Path "C:\Temp" -ItemType directory -Force
aws s3api get-object --bucket bucket1 --key Script.ps1 c:\temp\Script.ps1
c:\temp2\Script.ps1
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

If I go to http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/ within the EC2 instance then I can see the above lines of code.

Please let me know what is required to fix it?

Comment: Have you looked in the log? (`C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2Config.log`) Also, are you launching a _new_ instance, or are you starting an _existing_ instance?

Comment: Are you able to find the issue? I am having the same issue